# Fading RGBA colour changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create navigation bar which fades to an opacity of 80% when the user isn't at the top of the page. I've managed to get the scrolling and the corresponding CSS changes to work however I'm unsure with the fading. I've tried `.fadeTo()` which seemed to reduce the opacity to 0 and then fade the navigation bar in again instead of changing from 100% to 80%.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
        $('.top-navigation').css("background","rgba(53,61,64,0.8)")
    } else {
        if (scroll == 0) {
            $('.top-navigation').css("background","rgba(53,61,64,1)")
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: I presume I'd have to alter my code to not check every time the page is scrolled else it will fade everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like
to use CSS for the fade ?

**CSS**

```
 .topnavigation {
     opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}

.scrolled .topnavigation { opacity:0.5; }
```

**Then JS/jQuery ( add / remove the class )**

```
;(function() {

   /* this is the scroll */
   var _html = $('html');
   $(window).scroll(function(){
     var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (_scroll > 0) {  _html.addClass('scrolled'); } 
     else { _html.removeClass('scrolled'); }
   });


})();
```

Can see this **[running here](http://jsbin.com/komopovo/1/edit)** - as the 'scrolled' class was added to the `<html>` tag, it could be used in other areas/ css things now too ;

---

As your comment, yeah , you might like to be kinder on the scroll ( not to bad for this case ) - but if so, this will make the function only fire on scroll stop.

```
var _html = $('html'), var kinder;
$(window).scroll(function(){
 /* stop the function running until stop  */
 clearTimeout(kinder);
 kinder = setTimeout(function() {

  var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (_scroll > 0) {  _html.addClass('scrolled'); } 
    else { _html.removeClass('scrolled'); }

 },300);
});
```

---

*edit: update half opacity* as q

Comment: + adding the class is nice/future proof, as browsers that do not support css animate yet will fall back to a simple `opacity:0`